Why did Herr Konig kill his scientists and burn his notes?
In Cuckoo, at the climax of the film, a pair of scientists are performing an experiment having Alma meet her biological mother, presumably to observe how they would interact. Herr Konig, the owner of the preservation and the main villain, barges in after Gretchen and Henry shoot him and escape from his trap earlier. Herr Konig asks where the scientists keep the research notes, and then shoots them both. Later he is seen tossing the research into a fire, burning them.
My question is, why did he shoot them? They seemed to be much on his side of learning about the near-human species, and Herr Konig already orchestrated several attacks by the mother. Why does he seem intent on destroying everything he's worked for, despite his intent to continue preserving the mother and letting it reproduce?

Herr Konig is dedicated to the secrecy of the 'cuckoo' race.  He believes that humanity would not tolerate such a predator, and I agree with that.  I would certainly want them to be exterminated.
Konig does not ask Dr. Bonomo where she keeps the notes, he asks her to confirm they are still under her stairs at home.  Konig knew Dr. Bonomo had been secretly duplicating their research and keeping copies at her home, which he felt threatened his pet parasite project.
When his little conservation cottage resort thing was falling down around his ears, none of his reasons to keep the science staff alive applied anymore.  So he dispatched them. I personally enjoyed the sometimes ruthless 'conservationist' attitude being so deep in his character.

Ahh, so he was destroying anything that he didn't have any direct control over, which is why he left both the mother and Alma alive, while dispatching the others. I recall him saying something along the lines to Dr. Bonomo that this test was not being performed with his approval, too.

@Reeidly Really hard to find someone with the initiative to do mad science but also the obedience to let you drive!
